# Spring batch multithreading has a default limit of 10 implicitly?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch

I am using `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` to divide my job in to multiple `PartitionStep` (controlled by `gridSize`) and also use `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to process asynchronously in each step (controlled by `concurrencyLimit`).

So far, if `concurrencyLimit` is large enough (let's say 50), I observe that the **maximum concurrently processing of the whole batch job** is limited to `min(10, gridSize * 4)`.

With further testing, I identify the `4` in that formula can be modified by the `throttleLimit()` method of `SimpleStepBuilder`.

However, even if I configured `gridSize` and `throttleLimit` to some larger values, the overall concurrency never go over `10`. **Does anyone know where I can configure that limit?**

p.s. I am configuring the job programmatically, not with XML.

Comment: does your `AppConfig` implement `AsyncConfigurer` ?

Comment: @Palcente Thanks for pointing to this direction, I have looked further into http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html which talks about `AppConfig` and `AsyncConfigurer`. 

It says "By default, Spring will be searching for an associated thread pool definition: either a unique TaskExecutor bean in the context, or an Executor bean named "taskExecutor" otherwise."

I do have a bean returning `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.
```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("slaveTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {  }
```

Comment: Because I am using spring-batch, I have a Configurer extending `DefaultBatchConfigurer`. Do I need to have an `AppConfig` + `AsyncConfigurer`? And specify another task executor for the entire batch job?

Comment: if `DefaultBatchConfigurer` is of type `AppConfig`, then just add `AsyncConfigurer` type and you're good

Comment: actually I checked the above and noticed that you can set executor on the launcher level.. check the docs for `SimpleJobLauncher`

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but try to check if you are using HikariCP which has a default 10 simultaneous DB connexions limit

Just faced similar issue and resolved by increasing `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size`

See: [Number of parallel threads processing is capped to 10 with Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68267922/number-of-parallel-threads-processing-is-capped-to-10-with-spring-batch?noredirect=1#comment120679585_68267922)